# Transformation related to a particular random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Consider a random variable $Y$ with the density function given by
$$f_Y(y) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 2y^3 & -1 \leq y \leq 1 \\
                        0&\text{otherwise.} \end{array}\right.$$
I am trying to find the distribution for $Y^2.$ I can see that
$f_{Y^2}(y) = P(Y^2 \leq y) = P(-\sqrt{y} \leq Y \leq \sqrt{y}),$
But I am having issues figuring out what is the proper way to implement this
probability using information about $f_Y(y).$ Some assistance would be
appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a typo? $2y^3$ has negative values on $-1\leq y\leq 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, aside from the fact that your given density function is negative for $y<0$ (and its integral over the support is therefore zero; is there a typo somewhere?), your next step would be to take the derivative:

$$\begin{align}f_{Y^2}(y)
 & = \frac{\operatorname d }{\operatorname d y} \mathsf P(-\sqrt y \leq Y\leq \sqrt y) & \Big[y \in [0;1]\Big]
\\[2ex] & = \frac{\operatorname d }{\operatorname d y} \int_{-\sqrt y}^{\sqrt y} f_Y(z)\operatorname d z & \Big[y \in [0;1]\Big]
\end{align}$$